# protect WiFi shell-scripts against shell injection (sh, tcsh)

Tags: macos, wifi, code-injection, tcsh, openbsd

Ever saw a WiFi base station named `"| rm -rf ~ | rm -rf /`?

When scripting some kind of simple analysis or logging of WiFi base station data, how would one ensure that an attacker won't be able to inject shell commands into your expressions?

For example, I want to log data from `ifconfig run0 scan` on OpenBSD and [`airport -s` on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81221/how-do-i-get-wi-fi-info-from-within-terminal), and I already have some scripts in sh/tcsh that work great for my needs.  But how could I ensure that I don't become a victim of shell injections?

Answer (score 1):

this problem has been addressed to the OpenBSD lists (misc@) many times, as well as in other places.
first of all i would advise you to NOT execute things that you get from the network, specially in a script. Maybe you can edit your question to be more specific on what you want to do with these data so our answers could be tailored to it.

- if you want to use this info to connect to networks (as a network manager), put yourself between the script and the input. So after getting the output of scan just copy the nwid that you approve in your actual script. check out this [discussion on undeadly](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20120113172334)
- if you need to run automated scripts on the input for some other purpose (data gathering?), consider creating a chrooted dir , with your script and your statically compiled shell in it and run it chrooted. Of course you shouldn't rely on that approach for more sophisticated attacks than the one you mentioned in your question.

Hope this helps.